# Autohotkey DLLcall to CreateCaret returns 0 (The function failed) but A_LastError is also 0 (The function succeeded)

Tags: autohotkey, user32

I'm trying to use a simple AHK DLLCall to the user32 api function [CreateCaret](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-createcaret). I want it to give notepad a thick text caret.

```
caretWidth := 10
NULL := 0
Ptr := A_PtrSize ? "Ptr" : "UInt" ; If A_PtrSize is not defined, use UInt instead.
WinHwnd := WinExist("A")
result := Dllcall("CreateCaret", Ptr, WinHwnd, Ptr, NULL, "Int", caretWidth, "Int", 0)
msgbox % "LE " A_lasterror  ; Gives LE 0
msgbox % result  ; Gives 0
```

This should be equivalent to the following c++ call:

```cpp
CreateCaret(0x37072c, NULL, 10, 0);
```

Purposefully screwing up the function name makes result blank, so I believe the function is being called correctly. I just don't know why it is failing

Using similar code for `GetCursorBlinkRate` returns a sensible number.

I have also tried with `caretWidth := 0`

Similar questions about `GetLastError` are c++ calls, and AHK supposedly ensures that `GetLastError` is called in a timely enough manner to ensure A_lasterror is set correctly. Why is it showing no error code when the function apparently fails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change the caret of an external process.
If you try this for example, you'll see it works just fine if you own the process:

```
#Persistent
Gui, +hwndHWND
Gui, Add, Edit
Gui, Show

DllCall("CreateCaret", Ptr, HWND, Ptr, 0, Int, 50, Int, 50)
DllCall("ShowCaret", Ptr, HWND)

ESC::
GuiClose:
ExitApp
```

Comment: That's disappointing, but I'm not convinced it is the end of the story. [AML Maple](http://amlpages.com/amlmaple.shtml) manages to change  the cursor of arbitrary process's edit control. To be fair, they might not be using the user32 api.

Comment: Yeah, I wouldn't doubt that there's a way. What that way is though, I don't know.

Comment: You've technically answered the question so I'll give you the points